# Guidance for a CRM in .Net

Tags: .net, crm

My company is planning to build a new CRM system in .Net suitable for small/mid sized companies.I would like to know if there are any helpful books/blogs/tutorials/resources available for a developer on CRM fundamentals/development.

any sort of input would be highly appreciated

Regards,

Comment: This question does not fit very well in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) as you don't have any problems implementing something, but if you encounter any specific problems you're welcome to come back.

Comment: Is it not clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of these may help you

http://crm.codeplex.com/

or

http://www.jitbit.com/net-crm/

here is the comparison between available CRMs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_CRM_systems

Guidance:

Development requires planning. 
- Plan your project
- Do some analysis on existing CRMs and notice the services they provide.
(For this, some open source CRMs are available)

- Write down your plannings and services which should be provided by your CRM.
- Divide the whole project in different modules.
- Prepare the workflow of the module.
- Develop the module
- Test is with some real world inputs.
- integrate all the modules
- Plan and Do integration testing to test whether the integration worked well or not.
- Final, User Experience Testing, Bug finding, Resolving bugs, Evolution and that all.

You will have a better CRM with your own ideas and services implemented which might be a plus point against the exiting CRMs in the market.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks hiren! besides this are there any books on crm for a developer

Comment: There are some books available in the market. Do know much about them but here is one of them which I've found.

CRM as a Rapid Development Platform
http://www.amazon.com/CRM-as-Rapid-Development-Platform/dp/0981511813